# Method Not Getting Authorized in Spring Security despite Roles

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, role-based-access-control

I am getting Unauthorized error despite being logged in with User having the required roles.
In SecurityConfig, I used antMatchers, which allow me to do permitAll() but authorize when I use hasAnyAuthority(). On using annotations in methods, @PreAuthorize/@Secured , I am getting unauthorized error. When I debugged and checked all the Granted Authorities (in UserDetails) it was showing all the required roles but still the method with pre/post auth do not get authorized.

Here is what I coded:

### SecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig {
    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;

    @Bean
    public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        return new AuthTokenFilter();
    }


    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();

        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

        return authProvider;
    }



    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authConfig) throws Exception {
        return authConfig.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new ShaPasswordEncoder();
    }


    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .exceptionHandling(exception -> exception.authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler))
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth ->
                        auth.antMatchers("/authorizedAccess/**").permitAll()
                                .antMatchers("/api/v1/**").permitAll()
                                .antMatchers("/access/**").permitAll()
                                .anyRequest().authenticated()

                );

        http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());

        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

### Method:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/authorizedAccess")
public class AuthorizedAccessControl {

    @Autowired
    someService someService;

    private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(AuthorizedAccessController.class);

    /**
     *
     * @return
     */
    @Secured("hasAnyAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    @GetMapping(value = "/environments", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public List<String> getAllEnvironments() {

        LOG.debug(">>>Environments");
        return someService.getEnvironments();
    }
```

### AuthTokenFilter

```
public class AuthTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Autowired
    private JwtUtils jwtUtils;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(AuthTokenFilter.class);

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            String jwt = parseJwt(request);
            if (jwt != null && jwtUtils.validateJwtToken(jwt)) {
                String username = jwtUtils.getUserNameFromJwtToken(jwt);

                UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
                LOG.info(userDetails.getAuthorities());
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication =
                        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                                userDetails,
                                null,
                                userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
                List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>(authentication.getAuthorities());
                LOG.info(authorities);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Cannot set user authentication: {}", e);
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private String parseJwt(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String headerAuth = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        if (StringUtils.hasText(headerAuth) && headerAuth.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return headerAuth.substring(7);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

I tried putting checks on antMatcher and methods both. permitAll() works on antMatcher but neither permitAll() and hasAnyAuthority() work on both antMatcher or Method.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why are you building an insecure login? Jwts should not be used this way. They where never meant to be handed out to browsers. Jwt are used to authenticate between microservices and should not be handed out to browsers. So why have you buildt all of this?